# Check if this array includes any name that has "John" inside of it

Tags: javascript

There is an array, and I want to search the name that has 'john' (these four letters).

The boolean value  will return true.

```
const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];
```

What I tried in JS:

```
dragons.includes('John');
```

This returns false.

How should I use includes to cache that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `.some` instead, and use `startsWith` to check if any of the items in the array start with `'John'`:

```js
const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];
const anyJohn = dragons.some((name) => name.startsWith('John'));
console.log(anyJohn);
```

If `John` can be *anywhere* in the string (seems a bit odd), then instead use `.includes`:

```js
const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];
const anyJohn = dragons.some((name) => name.includes('John'));
console.log(anyJohn);
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use [Array::some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in conjuntion with [String::match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];

let res = dragons.some(x => x.match("John"));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Another way is use of `Regular Expression` like this:***

```js
const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'] ;
var result = /John/g.test( dragons.join(' ') ) ;
console.log( result ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter` which accepts a function,
function will execute for each element of array,
and if it returns `true`,
the element will remain in array.

in filter we can make use of `includes()` which tests if a string contains some Characters or not, if it has it returns true.

```
const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];
dragons.filter((name) => name.includes('John')); //['Johnathan']
```

Comment: Nice answer! It's better to attach the MDN docs for `.filter` and `.includes` for newcomers to easily understand your code

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dragons = ['Tim', 'Johnathan', 'Sandy', 'Sarah'];
dragons.includes('John'); //it will give us false
```

To find `John` within a name:

```js
const names=dragons.filter(name=>name.includes('John'));
console.log(names);
```